# Craft inequality 2

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

Hello I have to prove this , for $u$,$v$,$w$ the angles of a triangle an $p$ a natural number :

$$
 \sum_{cyc}\sin(\frac{u}{2^p})\sin(\frac{v}{2^p})+\sum_{cyc}\cos(\frac{u}{2^p})\geq\ \sum_{cyc}\cos(\frac{u}{2^{p+1}})\sin(\frac{u}{2^p})+\sum_{cyc}\sin(\frac{u}{2^{p+1}})\cos(\frac{u}{2^{p}})+\sum_{cyc}\sin(\frac{u}{2^{p+1}})\sin(\frac{v}{2^{p+1}})
$$

I can prove this for large values of p but not for small value :

I begin :

when p is large we have $sin(x)\simeq x$ and $cos(x)\simeq (1-\frac{x^2}{2})$ or $cos(x)\simeq 1$:

furthermore we put :
 $$X=\frac{u}{2^p};Y=\frac{v}{2^p};Z=\frac{w}{2^p}$$
then the inequality is

$$\sum_{cyc}XY+\sum_{cyc}(1-\frac{X^2}{2})\geq \frac{3}{2}\sum_{cyc}(X+Y+Z)+\sum_{cyc}\frac{XY}{2}$$
Wich is true

My question is : can you prove it for small value of p .